# weak-star convergence to Dirac Delta function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $Y=C_c((-1,1))$. Let $f_j=2j\chi_{(-1/j,1/j)}$, $f_j:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\Lambda_j:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\Lambda_j(g)=\int f_jg$ and $\Lambda: Y\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\Lambda(g)=g(0)$.

Show that $\Lambda_j$ converges to $\Lambda$ in the weak-star topology in $Y^*$.

**Attempt**:

I tried to prove for each $g\in Y$ that 
$$\lim g(0)-\int_{-1}^1 f_ig=0$$

but I don't know how helps the hypothesis that $g$ is an element of $C_c((-1,1))$.

Comment: Does $C_c$ mean "continuous with compact support"?

Comment: Yes, but I think one only needs continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function can be approximated by a fixed value.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|g(t)-g(0)|<\varepsilon$ for $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$. If $j>1/\delta$, then 
$$
\left|g(0)-\int_{-1}^1f_jg\right|=\left|\int_{-1}^1(g(0)-g(t))\,f_j(t)\,dt\right|\leq\int_{-1}^1|g(0)-g(t)|\,f_j(t)\,dt\\
\leq\varepsilon\,\int_{-1}^1f_j(t)\,dt=\varepsilon.
$$
This shows that $\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1f_jg=g(0)$.